# Antlr linphone line 2:0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 'V'

Tags: antlr, sip, linphone

I make a simple copy of the .g file in linphone sip decode antlr file to make things clear.
My problem is when I use this file  to decode sip's firstline it will failed sometimes.
The file is shown below:

```
    grammar sipmessage;
    options{
        language = Java;
        output = AST;
    }

    @lexer::header{
        package org.meri.antlr_step_by_step.parsers;
        import java.util.HashMap;
    }

    @parser::header{
       package org.meri.antlr_step_by_step.parsers;
       import java.util.HashMap;
    }

    status_line :    
        sip_version 
        sptab status_code {System.out.println($status_code.text);}
        sptab reason_phrase {System.out.println($reason_phrase.text);}
        CRLF
    ;

    sip_version   
        :    word;// 'SIP/' DIGIT '.' DIGIT;


    reason_phrase
       :    ~(CRLF)*;

    status_code     
        :    extension_code;

    word        
        :     
       (alphanum | mark   | '%'  
        | PLUS | '`' |
            LAQUOT | RAQUOT |
            COLON | '\\' | DQUOTE | SLASH | '[' | ']' | '?' | '{' | '}' 
        )+
    ;

    extension_code  :   DIGIT+;
    alphanum :  alpha | DIGIT ; 
    mark    :   '-' | '_' | '.' | '!' | '~' | STAR | '\'' | LPAREN | RPAREN ; 
    alpha   :   HEX_CHAR | COMMON_CHAR;     
    COMMON_CHAR :   'g'..'z' | 'G'..'Z' ;                

    HEX_CHAR:   'a'..'f' |'A'..'F';
    RPAREN  :   ')';
    LPAREN  :   '(';
    STAR    :   '*';
    DIGIT   : '0'..'9' ;
    PLUS: '+';
    COLON   :   ':';
    RAQUOT  :   '>';
    LAQUOT  :   '<';
    DQUOTE  : '"';
    SLASH   :   '/';

    SP  :   ' ';
    CRLF    : '\r\n';
    HTAB    : ' ';
    LWS :   (SP* CRLF)? SP+ ; //linear whitespace
    sptab : (SP|HTAB)+;
```

MyProblem is :when decode str eg:
"SIP/2.0 200 OK.\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.26.116:46448;alias;branch=z9hG4bK.TteIOuQeu;rport\r\n"
It can print firstline's status code and reason right.That's 200 and OK.

But if I add some spaces before the first \r\n before the Via that is,
"SIP/2.0 200 OK.      \r\nVia: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.26.116:46448;alias;branch=z9hG4bK.TteIOuQeu;rport\r\n"

The result is so wrong.
the reason printed out will become "OK.ia: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.26.116:46448aliasbranchz9hG4bK.TteIOuQeurport"

And I got a warning:"line 2:0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 'V'"

Can somebody tell me why ,I am not quite good at English and Antlr.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using TestRig to print the parse tree and token stream.

Comment: Ok,I will try to study this tool.Can you give me some tutorials,please.As I found it's hard to get some learning material which based on examples.Thank you so much.

Comment: The book is your best starting place.